# Overhead of wrapping synchronous methods in Task.Result

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Please consider the following interface example:

```
public interface ISomeAsyncService<T>
{
    Task<T> GetSomeObjectAsync(string id);
}
```

Now let's assume that some of the implementations of this interface do indeed retrieve objects asynchronously from a data store.
However, other implementations of this service might store objects in memory, for example:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeAsyncService<MyObject>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, MyObject> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
    public Task<MyObject> GetSomeObjectAsync(string id)
    {
        var obj = _dictionary[id];
        return Task.FromResult(obj);
    }
}
```

I'm doing this to be able to use the same interface for both synchronous and asynchronous services. It is not yet clear which service implementations will use static memory objects, and which will retrieve from a data store.

From what I understand, `Task.FromResult` will return immediately on the same thread.
Is there no overhead for using this approach as opposed to using synchronous methods (and a different interface) whenever possible? Even when most service calls will end up being to a synchronous implementation?

Comment: then i am thinking what would the benefit of using Tasks if no async work going on?

Comment: The only overhead is initialization of instance `TaskCompletitionSource`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the benefit is that I would be able to use the same interface for asynchronous and synchronous services, thus improving readability and maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced my `Task<T>` methods with the new C# 7 [`ValueTask<T>` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types):

```
public interface ISomeAsyncService<T>
{
    ValueTask<T> GetSomeObjectAsync(string id);
}
```

This reduces the overhead in case a Task is returning a synchronous result.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of doing `Task.FromResult(obj)` I would suggest making the method async and just returning obj.  That way there is no need to invoke the TaskScheduler in any way.

Here is the complete method.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeAsyncService<MyObject>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, MyObject> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
    public async Task<MyObject> GetSomeObjectAsync(string id)
    {
        var obj = _dictionary["id"];
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's going to be *more* overhead than using `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: I would argue that the overhead is worth it for the gains in simplicity, readability, and maintainability.

Comment: Your is less simple, it's *less* readable (you're creating an `async` method that's not asynchronous, it's not clear that the *purpose* is to wrap a synchronous operation in a `Task` rather than it being a mistake, whereas The *purpose* of `Task.FromResult` is to wrap an already computed value in a `Task`, so the extent is clear.  Regardless, the question didn't ask how to make the code more readable or simple, the question asked what the overhead, and you only ever proposed a *higher overhead* option.